# For what x the series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following problem:

For what values of x the following series:
$$  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n! \cdot (x-4)^n$$

a) Converges absolutely.

b) Converges conditionally.

I started by using the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {(n+1)!\cdot(x-4)^{n+1}}{n! \cdot (x-4)^n}$$

After simplifications:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  {(n+1)\cdot(x-4)}$$

But how to proceed from here?

Comment: What does $x-4$ do as $n$ approaches infinity?

Comment: You didn't post a series, but I assume you mean $\sum n! (x-4)^n$? Actually, it might be possible that you mean $\sum \frac{(x-4)^n}{n!}$, in which case the ratio you arrive at is not the correct ratio.

Comment: Which series you are talking about?

Comment: The series converges for $x=4$ and diverges otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $n!$ diverges faster than $x^{n}$, there exists no real value of $x$ other than 4 that creates a convergent series.

When $x=4$, the sum is $0+0\cdots$

Do not believe me? Try $x=3.99999999$ or $x=4.0000001$. Both diverge.